# Is there a limit to the number of instances a class can have in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I'm parsing a CSV file and storing the values into a class (each 'column' in the csv corresponds to an attribute of my class, Expense). My CSV has 15.000 rows. But after I go through all the lines, I only have 260 objects of the Expense class, instead of 15.000, which is the number of rows. If I parse a CSV with 100 rows, it works fine, it creates 100 objects of the Expense Class. But up from 150 rows it starts to create issues - 150 rows returns me 36 instances of the class Expense, and 15.000 returns 260. I don't see a logic, it is like at some point it resets the number of instances of my class and starts counting again.

Is there a limit to the number of instances a class can have in Ruby?

This is not a program, and I'm a real begginer. I'm just going a through a CSV, doing some validation on the data, and then returning to a CSV. So I was looking for way in which I didn't need to store the values in a temp file.

Thanks

Code:

```
class Expense
    attr_accessor :var1, :var2, :var3
    def initialize(var1,var2,var3)
        @var1 = var1
        @var2 = var2
        @var3 = var3
    end
    def self.count
        ObjectSpace.each_object(self).to_a.count
    end
end

old_file = File.read("C:/Folder/OldFile.csv")
new_file = File.new("C:/Folder/NewFile.csv", "w")
puts "Number of rows in input file: #{old_file.count("\n")}"
puts "Number of Expense objects stored before procedure: #{Expense.count}"

#loop through the rows and store each column as an attribute of the class
old_file.each_line do |line|
    #save each column of the row as an element of the array
    attr_ay = []
    line.chomp.each_line(';') do |att| 
        attr_ay.push(att.chomp(";"))
    end
    #loops through each attribute and assigns the corresponding value of the array
    i=0
    expense = Expense.new("","","")
    expense.instance_variables.each do |att|
        expense.instance_variable_set(att,attr_ay[i])
        new_file.print(expense.instance_variable_get(att)+";")
        i = i + 1
    end
    #jump to the next line in new file 
    new_file.print "\n"
end
new_file.close

#compare number of rows
new_file = File.read("C:/Folder/NewFile.csv")
puts "Number of rows in output file: #{new_file.count("\n")}"
puts "Number of Expense objects stored after procedure: #{Expense.count}"

#Result:
#Number of rows in input file: 15031
#Number of Expense objects stored before procedure: 0
#Number of rows in output file: 15031
#Number of Expense objects stored after procedure: 57
```

Comment: There is not a limit (ok there is a limit, but you won't hit it before running out of RAM/CPU). Your code most likely has a bug, it is worth posting the part that generates your objects from the CSV, so that we could look at it and help you figure it out. Also show how you are counting the instances - perhaps you are looking at the wrong thing at the end?

Comment: Hi Neil it is a long code, I will see if I can simplify it a little bit to post here. It is looping alright, because when I ask it to print to a new file during the execution of the parse method, it prints all 15000 rows and its columns to the new file. Is just not storing that many instances

Comment: I suspect that your problem is from using `ObjectSpace` to get the count. 1. That is an awful hack. 2. Ruby is probably doing some optimization in the background to save memory, thus the incorrect count. How about just storing the expenses in a regular array?

Comment: yeah, it works Max. you wanna know the strangest thing? I just added two lines to the code: created an expense_array and then expense_array.push inside the loop. The array stored all 15.031 objects, all right. But suddenly the ObjectSpace#each_object is also counting to 15.031. The simple act of pushing it to an array somehow changed how ObjectSpace#each_object works. Anyway, can you please post as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @Max: The objects were being garbage-collected because there was no reference to them. The ObjectSpace count was most likely accurate. Garbage collection will only start at all once you have used enough memory, which is why just a few lines appears to work OK. Without a reference you can use later (like the Array you suggested), creating the objects is has very limited use anyway, and there little point counting them, because you cannot access them.

Comment: thanks Neil that clarifies, it makes sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer based on comments by myself and Max that seem to of resolved the problem.

1. The code in the question is not being affected by any limit on number of objects. There is no limit inherent in the Ruby language, and most implementations allow for large numbers of objects, more than will fit into terabytes of memory. A script will typically run out memory or CPU time before it runs out of object pointers.
2. Using `ObjectSpace` to access the objects is the cause of the problem:

   1. `ObjectSpace` is a useful debugging tool or meta-programming tool, you can find current objects using it, but it does not maintain any active references.
   2. Ruby will clear up un-referenced objects, this is called garbage collection. It does this by checking all active bindings and following their object references (and all their child references etc). Anything not marked as "in use" in that mark phase can be removed in a later sweep phase.
   3. The garbage collection runs concurrently with your code, and only starts at all once the script has consumed at least some memory. This explains the puzzling changes of number when you tried different tests.
3. The fix is to use a container to hold the objects. Simply `push`-ing them on to an `Array` creates the necessary references, and stops garbage collection being a problem for you. You should use that variable to find and count your objects, not `ObjectSpace`.